# How to get userID from login on webbrowser c# for windows phone?

Tags: c#, parsing, webbrowser-control, windows-phone, userid

I am trying to retrieve the UserID that is returned once I have entered and submitted correct username and password.

I have been struggling to:

1. Close the Web-browser once it has successfully logged in. (it just redirects to a page with the UserID and has URL with user id in the end.
2. Retrieve the UserID once logged in.

I have tried this to retrieve the user id with no success.

```
        OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs ex)
                {
                base.OnNavigatedTo(ex); 
                IDictionary<string, string> parameters = NavigationContext.QueryString;      //once the login is successful this piece of code should be 
                 if (parameters.ContainsKey("id"))                                          //executed 
                     {
                    string UserId = parameters["id"];
                    }
                }
```

I have then tried the below. I get the current URL and not the loaded one. As well as that how can I parse it to just get the user id?

```
private void webBrowser2_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
 string URLString = e.Uri.ToString();
           txtURL.Text = URLString;
```

I think I am probably just having problems with the event handler and parsing.

Sorry, I am new to this so please forgive any mistakes I have made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigated event will fire each time a new page is loaded in the control. So the event will be fired first when your login page is navigated to, you would ignore this. The next time the event will fire as a result of navigation in the control and this time will either be from the user successfully logging in or a failure. Either way you'll need to read the Uri and parse out the relevant parameters. You can extract just the query elements from the uri using the Query property. See here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.95).aspx